# Angular filter : don't use the data of the other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array, with all the data, the complete list. I have a second array with only few of those data.

What I want to do is to filter the first one to get only the data that are different to the ones in the second array. And then make a third array with the filtered one.

Here are the arrays :

```
$scope.allparams = [{
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'title': 'Adhérent'
}, {
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'data': 'civilite',
    'lib': 'Civilité',
    'type': 'select'
}, {
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'data': 'nom',
    'lib': 'Nom',
    'type': 'text'
}, {
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'data': 'prenom',
    'lib': 'Prénom',
    'type': 'text'
}, {
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'data': 'dateNaissance',
    'lib': 'Date de naissance',
    'type': 'date'
}, {
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'data': 'nationalite',
    'lib': 'Nationalité',
    'type': 'select'
}, {
    'tab': 'ADH',
    'data': 'statut',
    'lib': 'Statut',
    'type': 'select'
}, {
    'tab': 'DET',
    'title': 'Détail comptable',
    'type': 'select'
}, {
    'tab': 'DET',
    'data': 'saison',
    'lib': 'Saison',
    'type': 'select'
}, {
    'tab': 'DET',
    'data': 'activite',
    'lib': 'Activité',
    'type': 'select'
}, {
    'tab': 'DET',
    'data': 'prix',
    'lib': 'Prix',
    'type': 'currency'
}];

if (exportService.getStockParams() != undefined) {
    // The second one, filled with a method
    var stockParams = exportService.getStockParams();
}
```

Here is an exemple of the second array :

```
    [{
    "tab": "ADH",
    "data": "nom",
    "lib": "Nom",
    "ordersource": 2,
    "added": true
}, {
    "tab": "ADH",
    "data": "prenom",
    "lib": "Prénom",
    "ordersource": 2,
    "order": null,
    "added": true
}, {
    "tab": "ADH",
    "data": "dateNaissance",
    "lib": "Date de naissance",
    "ordersource": 2,
    "order": null,
    "added": true
}]
```

Tell me if you need more details.

I'm new to Angular, and the filters seem quite hard to master.

Hope you could help.

Comment: " ... different to the ones in the second array" I see only one array $scope.allparams

Comment: The second one is `stockParams` filled with a method

Comment: plz provide example of the resulting second array, the data that is returned by exportService.getStockParams()

Comment: filter on the basis of which property? Do you want to filter in the code behind or thorough UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith) for this. Or without lodash with just filter and every methods of array.

```js
const all = [
  {x: 1, y: 2},
  {x: 1, y: 5},
  {x: 1, y: 6}
];

const partial = [
  {x: 1, y: 5}
];

const diff = difference(all, partial);

console.log(diff)

function difference(first, second) {
  return first.filter((item) => {
    return !second.every(angular.equals.bind(null, item));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I can prevent using a script file only for that, that would be better :/ But thanks

Comment: No problem, changed my answer, so that lodash is no longer used.

Comment: are you sure the op is using ES6? You are using a arrow function representation

Comment: This is only example and easy enough to write in es5.

Comment: In fact my problem could be resolved in a completely different way too specific in my case. But I tried your code anyway and it worked so I'll mark it as the solution :)